# How to extend schema with extra fields SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm new to SQLAlchemy and don't have a deep knowledge of it.

My question is how to extend a schema while instantiating it. In simple words, I want to add some extra fields in my schema while using it in code.

**FOR EXAMPLE**

In tags table there are two fields `tag` and `hex_color` and hence these two are in schema.

```
class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'
    schema = 'my_db'

    tag = Column(String(64), primary_key=True)
    hex_color = Column(String(8), nullable=False, default='#000000')


class TagSchema(SQLAlchemySchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        load_instance = True

    tag = fields.String(required=True, validate=validate.Length(min=1, max=64))
    hex_color = fields.String(validate=validate.Length(min=1, max=8))
```

While using it in my function like follows.

```
from some_file import TagSchema
 
schema = TagSchema()

body = schema.loads(event["body"])
```

Here `event["body"]` must contains `tag` or `hex_color` field.
I want to add extra fields in schema. Could it be possible?
Because my requirement is that the `event["body"]` could contain `service_name` field which is not present in `TagSchema` and could be loaded in this schema.

I want that event["body"] like following could be loaded in `TagSchema`.

```
{
  "tag": "some_tag",
  "hex_color": "#1a1a1a",
  "service_name": "Some Name
}
```

Is it possible? If yes then how?

Comment: What would you like to happen with `service_name`? Should it be accepted when you load the incoming data, but remain unused?

Comment: The only thing I want is to reuse the existing schema to validate the incoming request. That the request body should contain one of the existing fields.
But in this case `service_name` does not exist in schema and i have to define another schema to validate request.
Is there anyway to reuse the schema with extra field? Because the request can contain `service_name` which is not present in the schema.